# How to change the datum description of GeoTIFF in GDAL?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have found coordinate system discrepancies in my raster datasets.
Using gdalinfo 6 out of 500 of my images show the OGC WKT datum definition:

```
     GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
```

...whereas all the others have the datum defined in the ESRI WKT way, i.e

```
    PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N",
        GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",
        DATUM["ETRS_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
```

In order to do further processing in GDAL I need to create a VRT file. However GDALBUILDVRT fails due to this above discrepancy.

I have tried defining the coordinate system for the 6 files with the ESRI "define coordinate system" Tool and also the "Reproject" tool, but GDALINFO still displays the same datum information.

I have also tried defining and setting the coordinate system with SAFE FME, but to no avail.

GDAL_Edit also has no effect even when with the -unsetgt flag.

SO how can I change the definition?

Comment: Warping also the six images to ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N is the thing to do, I can't say why it fails for you.  You should have also noticed  that one is geographic coordinate system `GEOGCS` while the other is projected `PROJCS`.

Comment: But warping produces new files. Can't I just append the correct CRS definition to the GTIFF Header?

Comment: If you know that those images are actually in UTM projection but the data provider has made an error and attached wrong CRS info then yes, you can just edit the metadata. If the images are OK and they really are in different CRS you must warp them. Falsifying the CRS metadata will not help.

Comment: The images are all ok. I have been using them in an ESRI mosaic raster dataset for years. As far as I can tell, they have been assigned a distorted crs definition which I need to correct.

Comment: If the CRS is right then ESRI can re-project the images on-the-fly. So can QGIS. It can show without issues side-by-side images which are natively having different CRS. GDAL VRT cannot handle that case, so have a try, warp, and tell how it went.